# How to run jquery script if page is index.html

Tags: javascript, jquery

How to run jquery script if page is index.html.
When I entered URL in browser like http://qubedns.co.in/ is will automatically execute but not show the home page name (default).
Not show like http://qubedns.co.in/index.html

I want the current page name when user hit the url http://qubedns.co.in/ to run some script. If I get the page name 'index/html' I will finish it.

I used for other page

```
var currPageView = document.location.pathname.match(/[^\/]+$/)[0];
if(currPageView == 'index.html')
{
  // My Script here
}
```

I have try with:

```
var currPageView;
if($(location).attr('href')=='http://qubedns.co.in'){
    currPageView == window.location.host + '/' + 'index.html';
}else{
    currPageView = document.location.pathname.match(/[^\/]+$/)[0];
}
```

Is it right? any others solution ?

Comment: use `window.location.href.match(/index.html$/).length > 0`

Answer (score 0):

if your trying like this then you will get  total url

```
$(location).attr('href');
```

can you try like this ...and check this link also

http://en.proft.me/2014/08/1/how-work-location-url-javascript-jquery-angularjs/

```
var currPageView;
if($(location).attr('hostname')=='http://qubedns.co.in'){
currPageView == window.location.hostname + '/' + 'index.html';
}
```